# Addressing among private ip-addresses in networking

Tags: networking, ip-address, router, lan, nat

So, i was reading networking in depth. One concept i failed to understand was how different machines in LAN manage to access internet through one public IP address provided to company by ISP.

For eg. let's say the public address provided is 244.13.5.89. And all the machines when get to internet, they all are recognized as 244.13.5.89 despite their private address being 192.168.3.x, which is fine. But now when the router sends the request for each of these machines, how does it maps each response to respective machine?

If the answer is NAT, what entries does NAT has? Is there port no. or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give you the idea about the complex case scenario :-

> If all datagrams arriving at the NAT router from the WAN have the same
>   desti- nation IP address (specifically, that of the WAN-side interface
>   of the NAT router), then how does the router know the internal host to
>   which it should forward a given datagram?

The trick is to use a NAT translation table at the NAT router, and to
include port numbers as well as IP addresses in the table entries.

See more details about NAT Table [here](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/network-address-translation-nat/228-nat-table.html).

SORRY, don't know why it took me minutes to post an answer, it was not allowing me to add the answer...

Comment: what happened to your link? That was a good reading material.

Comment: @GRC-It is already given in the answer, if you're unable to access go here ---> http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/network-address-translation-nat/228-nat-table.html

Comment: it disappear for a minute from your answer!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman it still dont answer, how does it keep track as to which packet belongs to which local computer.

Comment: @user2025167- You should just reverse the logic for your case. The NAT table keeps internal IP's record along with port number as to which page is being requested by which IP---next it forwards the request publicly and when it returns, the rest I've already covered in the answer...

Comment: @user2025167-If it still doesn't help,please ask about your doubts. I'd be more than happier to resolve that. I'd also request you to go through the link which I've mentioned in my answer as well as in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

NAT has following fields:
source computer address and website, so when it receives packet it will replace source computer address with its public address, and send it to the internet once response comes back it sees  oh this come from the website and it was requested by the source computer. It will again replace destination address with source computer address and send it in LAN.

Comment: oh ok....but what if 2 different computers ask for exact same website??

Comment: IP address mainly, as well as time and port. It is worth mentioning that after two computers start connection they might change port on which they speak with each other.